# Poner márgenes en DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo esta tabla en una variable con un plugin llamado DataTable. Donde la uso para poder visualizar solicitudes (o Tickets) en una app de Mesa de Servicios.

```
var tableAdmin = $("#solicitudesAdmin").DataTable({
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: true,
                searching: true,
                ordering: true,
                responsive: true,
                colReorder: true,
                orderCellsTop: true,
                dom: 'lBfrtip',
                stateSave: true,
                stateDuration: 0,
                columnDefs: [
                    { width: '5%', targets: 0 }
                ],
                autoWidth: false,
                order: [[0, 'desc']],
                lengthMenu: [
                      [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                      ['10', '25', '50', '100', 'Todo']
                ],
                buttons: [
                      {
                          extend: 'colvis',
                          text: '<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> Columnas',
                      },
                      {
                          extend: 'excelHtml5',
                          filename: 'solicitudesAdmin',
                          title: 'solicitudesAdmin',
                          text: 'Exportar a Excel',
                          exportOptions: {
                              columns: ':visible',
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          text: 'Borrar Filtros',
                          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {

                              var coleccion = $("#solicitudesAdmin thead input");

                              console.log('Coleccion: ' + coleccion.length);
                              console.log('borrando con coleccion');
                              for (i = 0; i < coleccion.length - 1 ; i++) {
                                  console.log(i);
                                  elem = coleccion[i];
                                  if (elem != null) {
                                      console.log(elem.id);
                                      document.getElementById(elem.id).value = '';
                                  }
                              }
                              console.log('borrando');
                              var table = $('#solicitudesAdmin').DataTable();
                              table
                               .search('')
                               .columns().search('')
                               .draw();
                          }
                      }
                ],
                language: {
                    url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json'
                }
            });
```

Y se vería algo como así...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo o duda más bien sería que cómo podría mover o ponerle un poco más de margen entre los botones por ejemplo:

Que no esté tan pegado al combobox de los registros a visualizar y/o cambiarle el tipo de letra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo debes modificar el `dom` en los parámetros con los que inicializas datatable, te puedo dejar el link para que revises mas sobre ello en la página oficial:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Para resolver tu problema solamente deberías agregar un `div` con una clase en los botones para que puedas darle un margen izquierdo que lo separe del input de registros

```js
var tableAdmin = $("#solicitudesAdmin").DataTable({
  dom: 'l<"ml-2" B>frtip',
  scrollX: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging: true,
  searching: true,
  ordering: true,
  responsive: true,
  colReorder: true,
  orderCellsTop: true,
  stateSave: true,
  stateDuration: 0,
  columnDefs: [
      { width: '5%', targets: 0 }
  ],
  autoWidth: false,
  order: [[0, 'desc']],
  lengthMenu: [
        [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
        ['10', '25', '50', '100', 'Todo']
  ],
  buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'colvis',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i> Columnas',
        },
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            filename: 'solicitudesAdmin',
            title: 'solicitudesAdmin',
            text: 'Exportar a Excel',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: ':visible',
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Borrar Filtros',
            action: function (e, dt, node, config) {

                var coleccion = $("#solicitudesAdmin thead input");

                console.log('Coleccion: ' + coleccion.length);
                console.log('borrando con coleccion');
                for (i = 0; i < coleccion.length - 1 ; i++) {
                    console.log(i);
                    elem = coleccion[i];
                    if (elem != null) {
                        console.log(elem.id);
                        document.getElementById(elem.id).value = '';
                    }
                }
                console.log('borrando');
                var table = $('#solicitudesAdmin').DataTable();
                table
                 .search('')
                 .columns().search('')
                 .draw();
            }
        }
  ],
  language: {
      url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.25/i18n/Spanish.json'
  }
});
```

```css
.ml-2 {
  margin-left: .5rem;
}
```